# Use Tracker.autorun to monitor limit changes but not new posts

Tags: meteor

I want to use

```
// client
var limit = Session.get('postsLimit');
Tracker.autorun(function (c) {
     Meteor.subcribe('posts', limit);
     c.stop();
});

// server
Meteor.publish('posts', function (limit) {
     return Posts.find({}, {limit: limit});
});
```

because I don't want the insertion of new posts to affect a user's experience while viewing the posts that were loaded when a user first visits the page. But at the same time, I want the tracker to still recognize limit changes so that it can load posts as the user scrolls. So in other words, I want the tracker to stop subscribing to brand new post after the initial load but still load posts that have already been created.
How can I do this with Tracker or perhaps Tracker isn't the best option?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a client only collection, insert the posts into that and make your helpers return the local collection.
Use `observeChanges` to watch the for newly added posts, when there are new posts, show the user an appropriate message. When the user wants to view the new posts, add them to the client only collection.

Comment: Okay I'll try this out.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use `observeChanges` to watch for newly added posts and prevent incoming posts. I'm confused about `added` function.  I've been using it alter each post server-side. `var cursor = Posts.find(); cursor.observeChanges({
  added: function (id, post) {
   changePost(post);
   sub.added('posts', id, post);
  }});` So how can I change the posts that I want while also denying newly inserted posts?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
//client.js
var now = new Date(); //so the now never change
Tracker.autorun(function (c) {
   Meteor.subscribe('posts', now,  Session.get('postsLimit'));
});


//server.js
Meteor.publish('posts',function(time,limit){
  return Posts.find({savedAt: {$lt: time}},{limit:limit});
});
```

So when each post is saved into the database, a savedAt field is also appended and the query only searches for those saved before the current time.

Instead of using var now = new Date(); you can also use `Session.get('now')` then you can change it later by `Session.set('now',new Date)` when a user decides to fetch everything new.

However have to be aware of the time differences between client and server, may need to synchronise them?

Comment: But then every time the limit is incremented, the publication updates.